# Heroku deploying. I can't see any error but my application is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql, heroku

I've deployed my apps several times on heroku and everything was fine.

Now I'm trying to deploy my app and got error "We're sorry, but something went wrong". It takes me 1 day trying to solve this problem. I've done rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production and there was no any problems.
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false in my application.rb

Probably there is some mistakes with my database.yml?

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 10000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 10000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db/production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```

Here's log after git push heroku master:

```
 -----> Ruby/Rails app detected
    -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
    -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
           Running: bundle install --without development:test --path                    
                   vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
           Using rake (10.1.0)
           Using i18n (0.6.5)
           Using minitest (4.7.5)
           Using multi_json (1.8.0)
           Using atomic (1.1.13)
           Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
           Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
           Using activesupport (4.0.0)
           Using builder (3.1.4)
           Using erubis (2.7.0)
           Using rack (1.5.2)
           Using rack-test (0.6.2)
           Using actionpack (4.0.0)
           Using mime-types (1.25)
           Using polyglot (0.3.3)
           Using treetop (1.4.15)
           Using mail (2.5.4)
           Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
           Using activemodel (4.0.0)
           Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
           Using arel (4.0.0)
           Using activerecord (4.0.0)
           Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
           Using sass (3.2.10)
           Using bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.2)
           Using will_paginate (3.0.4)
           Using bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9)
           Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
           Using execjs (2.0.1)
           Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
           Using thor (0.18.1)
           Using railties (4.0.0)
           Using coffee-rails (4.0.0)
           Using commonjs (0.2.7)
           Using daemon_controller (1.1.5)
           Using delayed_job (4.0.0)
           Using delayed_job_active_record (4.0.0)
           Using orm_adapter (0.4.0)
           Using warden (1.2.3)
           Using devise (3.0.3)
           Using dotenv (0.9.0)
           Using faker (1.2.0)
           Using multipart-post (1.2.0)
           Using faraday (0.8.8)
           Using foreman (0.63.0)
           Using tilt (1.4.1)
           Using haml (4.0.3)
           Using haml-rails (0.4)
           Using hashie (2.0.5)
           Using hike (1.2.3)
           Using httpauth (0.2.0)
           Using jbuilder (1.5.1)
           Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
           Using json (1.8.0)
           Using jwt (0.1.8)
           Using kgio (2.8.0)
           Using less (2.4.0)
           Using less-rails (2.4.2)
           Using libv8 (3.11.8.17)
           Using oauth2 (0.8.1)
           Using omniauth (1.1.4)
           Using omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
           Using omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
           Using omniauth-vkontakte (1.2.0)
           Using paginate (3.0.0)
           Using passenger (4.0.17)
           Using pg (0.15.1)
           Using bundler (1.3.2)
           Using sprockets (2.10.0)
           Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
           Using rails (4.0.0)
           Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
           Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.2)
           Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
           Using raindrops (0.12.0)
           Using rdoc (3.12.2)
           Using ref (1.0.5)
           Using sass-rails (4.0.0)
           Using sdoc (0.3.20)
           Using therubyracer (0.11.4)
           Using turbolinks (1.3.0)
           Using twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8)
           Using uglifier (2.2.1)
           Using unicorn (4.6.3)
           Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
           Cleaning up the bundler cache.
    -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
    -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
           Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
    -----> Discovering process types
           Procfile declares types      -> web, worker
           Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake

    -----> Compiled slug size: 63.2MB
    -----> Launching... done, v9
           http://infinite-tor-5194.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

    To git@heroku.com:infinite-tor-5194.git
       864973b..5cdfe38  master -> master
    root@User1:/usr/src/rbpr/d23m# heroku open
    Opening infinite-tor-5194... done
```

And here's my heroku log:

```
 root@User1:/usr/src/rbpr/d23m# heroku logs
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.866061+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.866337+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.867305+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.867305+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920595+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920595+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920595+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_toke...
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920595+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920595+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1):
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920595+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:20:in `current_user'
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920595+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `signed_in?'
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920595+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920595+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920595+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:4:in `home'
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920899+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920899+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920899+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_toke...
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920899+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920899+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1):
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920899+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `signed_in?'
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920899+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920899+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:20:in `current_user'
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920899+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:4:in `home'
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.920899+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T07:18:32.923140+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=infinite-tor-5194.herokuapp.com fwd="89.169.49.29" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=226ms status=500 bytes=1266
    2013-09-11T08:24:35.824290+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.013048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.958893+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-11 08:24:40] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.958893+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.958893+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.958893+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.958893+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.958893+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.958893+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.958893+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.959070+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-11 08:24:40] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.958893+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.959070+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.959070+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.959070+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.959070+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.959070+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-11 08:24:40] INFO  going to shutdown ...
    2013-09-11T08:24:40.958893+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    2013-09-11T08:24:43.400338+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
    2013-09-11T08:24:43.410429+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2013-09-11T10:18:56+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
    2013-09-11T10:19:46.285001+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 5cdfe38 by davydenkov_m@mail.ru
    2013-09-11T10:19:46.312851+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by davydenkov_m@mail.ru
    2013-09-11T10:19:47+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
    2013-09-11T10:19:46.743756+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2013-09-11T10:19:52.854779+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 18250`
    2013-09-11T10:19:57.859418+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:103: warning: already initialized constant #<Module:0x007f2890f30790>::AttrNames
    2013-09-11T10:19:57.859418+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:103: warning: previous definition of AttrNames was here
    2013-09-11T10:19:57.869819+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:103: warning: already initialized constant #<Module:0x007f28910e6cd8>::AttrNames
    2013-09-11T10:19:57.867077+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:103: warning: already initialized constant #<Module:0x007f289109fef0>::AttrNames
    2013-09-11T10:19:57.867077+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:103: warning: previous definition of AttrNames was here
    2013-09-11T10:19:57.869819+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:103: warning: previous definition of AttrNames was here
    2013-09-11T10:19:57.931113+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-11 10:19:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    2013-09-11T10:19:57.931819+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-11 10:19:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=18250
    2013-09-11T10:19:57.931113+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-11 10:19:57] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
    2013-09-11T10:19:58.535447+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.560065+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.560065+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:18250
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.560065+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.560065+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.560065+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 89.169.49.29 at 2013-09-11 10:28:10 +0000
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.560065+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 89.169.49.29 at 2013-09-11 10:28:10 +0000
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.630935+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.630935+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.664056+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.664056+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.664056+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_toke...
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.664056+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.665348+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_toke...
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.665348+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.665348+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.665935+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35ms
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.667812+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.667812+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.667812+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_toke...
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.665348+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.665804+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35ms
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.667812+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.667812+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1):
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.667812+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `signed_in?'
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.667812+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:4:in `home'
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.667812+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.675509+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.675509+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.667812+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:20:in `current_user'
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.667812+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.675509+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_toke...
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.675509+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1):
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.675509+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:20:in `current_user'
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.675509+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `signed_in?'
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.675509+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.679234+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=infinite-tor-5194.herokuapp.com fwd="89.169.49.29" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=124ms status=500 bytes=1266
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.675509+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:4:in `home'
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.675509+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T10:28:10.675509+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-09-11T10:28:11.377794+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=infinite-tor-5194.herokuapp.com fwd="89.169.49.29" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=0
```

UPDATE:

```
 root@User1:/usr/src/rbpr/d23m# heroku run rake db:reset
 Running `rake db:reset` attached to terminal... up, run.9279
 FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
 DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
 ...
 Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "username"=>"acnvttimesbqxk",    
 "password"=>"xzwY-0W8-JkXPwFobd3-gE8syk", "port"=>5432, "database"=>"d6vpf68f9ersl9", 
 "host"=>"ec2-54-227-238-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com"}
  -- create_table("delayed_jobs", {:force=>true})
 rake aborted!
 FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
 DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

Comment: FYI - database.yml is rewritten on deployment to Heroku to suit their environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run migration for your app `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Please see my update, i have provide heroku run rake db:reset results

Comment: In heroku, if you want to reset your database, run `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` and then `heroku run rake db:migrate` -- rake db:reset doesn't work on heroku

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your `production:` section from your `config/database.yml` because heroku injects this on deployment

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with heroku deployment try to use command

```
heroku run rake db:setup
```

It helps me to solve this problem with deployment, when heroku pg:reset gives me nothing